# Image rendering in React with webpack broken

Tags: html, reactjs, image, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to render an image on my React Web App, but the image is broken. However, when I do a console.log of the file's path, I see the following which seems to be correct. 
We are using url-loader and file-loader with webpack, and am importing the file path directly in the import statements as required. I have tried adding required ('imageFilePath.png'), but that did not work either.

Currently, the image is placed directly in the src folder along with App.js.

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import {Tweet} from 'react-twitter-widgets';
import logoFinal from './logoFinal.png';

class App extends Component {
render () {
    const { error, isLoaded} = this.state;
    if (error){
      return <div> Error: {error.message}</div>
    } else if (!isLoaded){
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    } else{
    return (

     <div className="container">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
        <div className="container">
          <a className="navbar-brand pull-left" href="/home">
          <div>
          <img src={require('./logoFinal.png')} width='100' margintop='-7' /></div></a>
<button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div className="navbar-nav">
              <a className="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              <a className="nav-item nav-link" href="#">By State</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

And then in my webpack.config.js I have the following in the module section:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,  
  use: [{
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: { 
      limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
      name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
    } 
  }]
},
{
  // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
  // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
  // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
  oneOf: [
    // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
    // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
    // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
    {
      test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
      loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
      options: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
      },
    },
```

Comment: have you tried `<img src={logoFile} ... />`?

Comment: Note: the size of the image is 264KB. Not sure if that exceeds limits for how webpack loads the image onto the page.

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez yes I have. Just realized this is slightly old code, but I have tried <img src-{logoFile} /> but to no avail

Comment: it should be `src={logoFile}` (the equal sign)

Comment: the limit will be used to convert small images to base64 strings, not really relevant..

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

With this line, you have imported the image.

```
import logoFinal from './logoFinal.png';
```

The `logoFinal` variable will be the actual image-path, which will be generated by webpack. So you can use it in the `<img />` tag as the `src` attribute.

```
<img src={logoFinal} />
```

You **webpack config** looks weird, because you have defined two rules for images. The later one with `require.resolve('url-loader')` seams to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Natalie. I've removed the extra url-loader in the web pack and kept the second. I've tried the suggestions and the image still renders as broken. I see the img in the html as this: http://localhost:3000static/media/logoFinal.fb830421.png

I've also attempted to use file-loader.